# SQLi newbie connect and close

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm pretty new in MySQLi and I'm not really sure about how to deal with it.
So advices are welcome even is everything seems to work fine.

I made a class in a connection file :

```
<?php
class Connection{
var $hostname;
var $hostnameStr;
var $dbName;
var $user;
var $pswd;
var $connectObj;
function __construct(){
    $this->hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    $this->hostnameStr = "localhost";
    $this->user = "userName";
    $this->pswd = "mypassword";
}
function connect2db($db){
    $this->dbName = $db;
    $this->connectObj =  new mysqli($this->hostnameStr,$this->user,$this->pswd);
    $this->connectObj->set_charset('utf8');
    return $this->connectObj;
    }
}
?>
```

So far so good, but it's probably not a good approach.
In another php file i do :

```
<?php
            require_once("../../Connections/connection.php");
            $connect = new Connection();
            $connection = $connect->connect2db("myDbName");
            $result_test = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY uid ASC");
            while ($row = $result_test->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<p>" . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . "</p>";
            }
<?>
```

Is it the best way to connect to a database when you have a lot of DB?
When I'm trying to close the connection, everything looks to be alright too.

```
<?php
    optional
    echo "closed = " . ($connection->close());
    // this gives me true / 1
?>
```

I began to learn this two days ago, so this may be unclear or completely nonsense.  All seems to working fine, but I'm sure there's different ways to make the code more efficient.

Any suggestions?

Is it another way to close the connection when the results are displayed?
Am I studying in the bright side of code or this is just a mistake to work as this?

A real newbie question, but I hope that someone will be able to explain me the basics ?!

Should I make a PDO request like instead as I see this on an example???

```
$pdo = new PDO([params])...
```

A little confused here!

PS : I didn't run "WAMPSERVER" and I'm working on IIS7 with phpmyadmnin, PHP 5.3 (dll) and PHP 7.0.1 as Fast cgi, Windows 10.

Comment: Google about `singleton php database connection`

Comment: Side note: the `var` keyword is part of the PHP/4 OOP syntax. Even PHP/5.3 is unsupported. Learning with outdated tutorials is a fairly common beginner mistake.

Comment: I wrote another subject that I told about....
The replies were "Do U really need a Singleton in this case?
However, I will Google it ;)
Thank you for your quick reply!!!
Sincerely Nicolas.

Comment: The first question is, why would you "have a lot of DB". And what a "DB" is.

Comment: The second question is, how is your custom class better than native mysqli class?

Comment: I told you, I learn PHP7 and my SQLi since 2 days and I'm really confused.
I have a lot of DB's because I have a lot of websites...
In PHP5 it was not a problem.
This could be a fresh and new start...
Understanding what you're doing is better than use code snipsets...
I have to Google a lot so, but if somebody have some time to spend to give me useful links it may be useful...

Comment: Thank you for this time spent about this newbie question however!

Comment: Sry Rocket Hazmat, but what was edited?
My question was unclear probably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starter, make your code like this:

connection.php:

```
<?php
$hostname = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "userName";
$pswd = "mypassword";
$database = "myDbName";
$charset = "utf8";

$connection = new mysqli($hostname,$user,$pswd,$database);
$connection->set_charset($charset);
```

and in another file

```
<?php
require_once("../../Connections/connection.php");
$result_test = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY uid ASC");
while ($row = $result_test->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<p>" . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . "</p>";
}
```

and it will let you to use the same code on different sites by means of changing their credentials in the connection.php file only.

But if you are open for the good advise, and want to avoid A LOT of trouble, go for PDO instead of mysqli. Here is a [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) I wrote, which will help you to start using it the proper way.

Comment: This was the manner I did it first, you're right my class is totally useless.
I will read, try, test, then I'll be back to you.

Comment: Good, feel free to ask.